# How to create to the specific host/post a client to the specific host/post in JReJSON with password?

Tags: java, redisjson

This is how javadoc mentions the definition of JReJSON

```
JReJSON(String host, int port)
Creates a client to the specific host/post a client to the specific host/post
```

but there is provision to provide password

along with host and port as only two parameters are not enough for creating client as auth is missing which is enabled through providing password

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the `JReJSON(Pool<Jedis> jedis)` constructor.

E.g.

```
new JReJSON(new JedisPool(host, port, user, password))
```

If your Redis version is older than Redis 6 or if you don't want to use the `user` param:

```
new JReJSON(new JedisPool(host, port, null, password))
```